# Drop rows where a subset of columns are empty in Pandas

Tags: pandas, drop

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format

```
No  ei1  ei2  ei3  ei4  ei1_val  ei2_val  ei3_val  ei4_val
123
124
125  0   0    0    1    low      low      high     high
```

To simplify, I have shown only a subset of columns here but actually the pandas dataframe has columns from ei1 to ei24 and ei1_val to ei24_val.

I have retrieved the column names using the below code:

```
val_cols = df[[col for col in df.columns if col.endswith("_val")]]
cols = [col.replace('_val', '') for col in val_cols.columns]
```

After that, I need to drop the rows from dataframe df if all columns in val_cols and all columns in cols are empty. Hence the output dataframe would drop rows with No's 123 and 124. Not sure whether is there a way to do it efficiently in Pandas rather than looping over the columns and checking the values.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How is empty defined? Are those empty strings or `NaN`?

Comment: @HenryEcker: They are all empty strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
m = ~df.filter(regex='.*_val').isna().all(axis=1)
df[m]
```

Output:

```
    No  ei1  ei2  ei3  ei4 ei1_val ei2_val ei3_val ei4_val
2  125  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0     low     low    high    high
```

Find all the columns where the column header ends with _val using regex in the `pd.DataFrame.filter` method.

Check to see if all values are NaN using isna and all with axis=1

Comment: [OP confirms they're empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873727/drop-rows-where-a-subset-of-columns-are-empty-in-pandas?noredirect=1#comment119969357_67873727) not NaN. `.eq('').all(axis=1`) should be a quick fix?

Comment: FWIW, the regex isn't really checking for ends-with, it might as well match a string that starts with `_val`, but doesn!t matter here i guess `:)`